# How do you syntax check and format code for C in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm used to programming Java in Intellij, where I can download extensions for Java syntax checker and Google style formatting. I'm wondering if there is an equivalent alternative in Visual Studio 2019 for C?

Comment: It should support C by default.

Comment: @dbush it does for sure (actually C++)

Comment: It does support it, but whenever I type into the environment, there is no checking for syntax. Like if I just type hello into Intellij there would be a squiggly red line, and that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @JiaqiShao it works in VS "out of the box". No extensions needed.